# CSS for first-child is not getting applied

Tags: html, css

I need to increase the height of the 1st panel which is in ng-repeat

**Code**

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-height" ng-repeat="candidateInfo in aCandidateDetails">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <a style="cursor:pointer">
                {{candidateInfo.name}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div stop-watch time="xyz" name="candidateInfo.name" time-of-interview="candidateInfo.doi" ></div>
</div>
```

Here i have applied css to the class .panel-height as below

```
.panel-height:first-child {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Here the css is not getting applied ,
I cannot figure out where im going wrong .
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to put ur code in fiddle or codepen

Comment: did you try .panel-height:first-of-type ?

Comment: If the `panel-height` div is not the `:first-child` the selector will not work. If you are trying to target the first-child OF `panel-height`, then your selector is wrong.

Comment: here is the plunker link what i have tried https://plnkr.co/edit/MMVmaFtBeaJ1Pb0N2lmx?p=preview

Comment: It is working fine here but i m using sass in my application the same css code is not working there

Comment: @Shikhathakur In plnkr you have used `first-of-type` while in sass you are using `first-child`. Both are different selectors, check them carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to 'panel-heading' only when the div satisfies $first and then add height to the class name 'firstChild'.

```html
<div class="panel panel-default panel-height" ng-repeat="candidateInfo in aCandidateDetails">
<div class="panel-heading" ng-class="{'firstChild':$first}"> <!-- Try this line -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <a style="cursor:pointer">
                {{candidateInfo.name}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div stop-watch time="xyz" name="candidateInfo.name" time-of-interview="candidateInfo.doi" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, well try this,

```
.panel-height:nth-child(1) {
    height: 500px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```